# How would I convert a number into binary bits, then truncate or enlarge their size, and then insert into a bit container?

Tags: stl, binary, numbers, bit, truncation

As the title of the question says, I want to take a number (declared preferably as `int` or `char` or `std::uint8_t`), convert it into its binary representation, then truncate or pad it by a certain variable number of bits given, and then insert it into a bit container (preferably `std::vector<bool>` because I need variable bit container size as per the variable number of bits). For example, I have `int a= 2, b = 3`. And let's say I have to write this as three bits and six bits respectively into the container. So I have to put `010` and `000011` into the bit container. So, how would I go from `2` to `010` or `3` to `000011` using normal STL methods? I tried every possible thing that came to my mind, but I got nothing. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of 'shifting' (`>>`) and 'bit-wise and' (`&`).

First lets look at the bitwise `&`: For instance if you have an `int a=7` and you do the `&`-operation on it with 13, you will get 5. Why?
Because & gives 1 at position i iff both operands have a 1 at position i. So we get:

```
  00...000111  // binary 7
& 00...001101  // binary 13
-------------
  00...000101  // binary 5
```

Next, by using the shift operation `>>` you can shift the binary representation of your `int`s. For instance `5 >> 1` is 2. Why?
Because each position gets displaced by 1 to the right. The rightmost bit "falls out". Hence we have:

```
00...00101 //binary for 5
shift by 1 to the right gives:
00...00010 // binary for 2
```

Another example: 13 (01101) shifted by 2 is 3 (00011). I hope you get the idea.

Hence, by repeatedly shifting and doing `&` with 1 (00..0001), you can read out the binary representation of a number.

Finally, you can use this 1 to set the corresponding position in your `vector<bool>`. Assuming you want to have the representation you show in your post, you will have to fill in your vector from the back. So, you could for instance do something along the lines:

```
unsigned int f=13; //the number we want to convert
std::vector<bool> binRepr(size, false); //size is the container-size you want to use.
for(int currBit=0; currBit<size; currBit++){
 binRepr[size-1-currBit] = (f >> currBit) & 1;
}
```

If the container is smaller than the binary representation of your int, the container will contain the truncated number. If it is larger, it will fill in with 0s.

I'm using an `unsigned int` since for an `int` you would still have to take care of negative numbers (for positive numbers it should work the same) and we would have to dive into the two's complement representation, which is not difficult, but requires a bit more bit-fiddling.